# How to display description on Woocommerce featured products?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I trying to add the the product description to all my related products.
This is the code I have from content-single-product.php template file:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
```

This is not working good for me because `@hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20` has the image, title and price inside.

What I want is to have for each related product, the description under the product title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will display only on related products section, the description under the product title (on single product pages):

```
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'description_after_related_product_title', 15 );
function description_after_related_product_title(){
    global $woocommerce_loop, $product;

    // Only for related products: Display product description
    if( isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && 'related' === $woocommerce_loop['name'] ) {
        echo '<p class="description">' . $product->get_description() . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: and if i want it to be display in all my pages also in product categories the same way

Comment: @davidasor if you want to display that on all loop pages too, simply remove `if( isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && 'related' === $woocommerce_loop['name'] ) {` and the closing related bracket `}`